# Speeding up GDI+ when Handling Large Images in c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+

Im using GDI+ to render images in c#.The method works fine when Medium quality images are used.But when i use High quality images with large sizes ranging from 1.5-5mb the processing seems to be much slower.I mainly use

```
Graphics.DrawImage
```

Is there any way to speed up this.Can i reduce the size of the images on the fly by compressing it in memory,Will this take more time.Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

If not scaling the image, DrawImageUnscaled will help.  Consider setting to premultiplied RGBA as well.  Split the image into smaller chunks.

See here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/467752-maximizing-gdi-speed/

Comment: Can you please provide some example

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been a similar question: [How to increase performance over GDI's DrawImage(Unscaled)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587911/how-to-increase-performance-over-gdis-drawimageunscaled)

That guy ended up writing his own library on top of OpenTK to really speed up things.