# Automatically add watermark to an image

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, image-processing

while searching for a solution to automatically put a watermark to an image in internet, i found a best solution in stackoverflow.  Link for the question is [C# - Add watermark to the photo by special way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113900/c-sharp-add-watermark-to-the-photo-by-special-way).  My special thanks to  **Alex Maslakov** and **adrift**.

I implemented that solution with some modifications, i want to put watermark in center of the image.  I modified the solution provided by **adrift** as follows

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"))
        using (Image watermarkImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\watermark.png"))
        using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        using (Brush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
        {
            int x = (image.Width - watermarkImage.Width)/2;
            int y = (image.Height - watermarkImage.Height)/2;
            imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), watermarkImage.Size));
            image.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert_watermark.jpg");
        }

    }
```

but watermark is not properly placed in the center of image (see below image).

[image]

please correct me...

thanks

Comment: It honestly looks centered to me. Can you replace that watermark image with a box for clarity on where it's off?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally i find the solution to my question...

The corrected code answer is following

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"))
        using (Image watermarkImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\watermark.png"))
        using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
        {
            int x = (image.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
            int y = (image.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
            watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
            imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width+1, watermarkImage.Height)));
            image.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert_watermark.jpg");
        }

    }
```

my thanks to Furqan Safdar and Abdias Software 
The link [Problem in tiling image starting at different height using TextureBrush in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333869/problem-in-tiling-image-starting-at-different-height-using-texturebrush-in-c-sha) also helped me to solve this problem

and thanks all

finally result

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Your original formula is fine btw.,

are you making sure the resolution of the two are the same? Set DPI resolution of your watermark image equal to image:

```
watermarkImage.SetResolution(imageGraphics.DpiX, imageGraphics.DpiY);
```

(from the top of my head, but i think the property names are correct).

UPDATE:

Change from Image to Bitmap in order to use `SetResolution()` - See if this change works for you - I've changed the way the watermark is drawn onto the image:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    using (Bitmap image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"))
    using (Bitmap watermarkImage = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\watermark.png"))
    using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        watermarkImage.SetResolution(imageGraphics.DpiX, imageGraphics.DpiY);

        int x = ((image.Width - watermarkImage.Width) / 2);
        int y = ((image.Height - watermarkImage.Height) / 2);

        imageGraphics.DrawImage(watermarkImage, x, y, watermarkImage.Width, watermarkImage.Height);

        image.Save("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert_watermark.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: image's resolution is 72dpi and watermarkimage's resolution is 96dpi, i can't find the function specified above, so changed watermarkimage's resolution to 72dpi manually, but no change in result

Comment: I have changed your routine a little in the way it draws the waterwark. See if that works.

Comment: Finally i found the solution to solve problem,  please see my own answer.  many many thanks for you for your support

Comment: Impossible to converto from Image to Bitmap

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for center alignment:

```
int x = (image.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
int y = (image.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
```

Comment: i implemented your solution, but no change in result, see edited photo

Comment: By the way it is center aligned but cutting from edges which is mainly due to less size of brush probably. Try increasing the brush size to testing.

Comment: There is no difference in the calculated result with this compared to original.

Comment: @FurqanSafdar Here image size 1024 x 768 and watermark image size 213 x 53 pixels

Answer (score 1):

**Working sample:**

```
public static Bitmap WatermarkImage(Bitmap image, Bitmap watermark)
{
    using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        watermark.SetResolution(imageGraphics.DpiX, imageGraphics.DpiY);

        int x = (image.Width - watermark.Width) / 2;
        int y = (image.Height - watermark.Height) / 2;

        imageGraphics.DrawImage(watermark, x, y, watermark.Width, watermark.Height);
    }

    return image;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Bitmap watermark = new Bitmap(@"c:/watermark.png");
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"c:/image.png");
bitmap = WatermarkImage(bitmap, watermark);
bitmap.Save(@"C:/watermarkedImage.png");
```