# Apply watermark on webp image

Tags: c#, file-upload, webp

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870849/3952692) solution to apply water-mark to image, here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{                        
    Image imgg = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@"\Images\WaterMark.png"));

    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];

    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, true, true)) //Parameter is not valid exception on uploading .webp file
    using (Image watermarkImage = imgg)
    {
         using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
         using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
         {
              int x = 4;
              int y = image.Height - watermarkImage.Height - 30;
              watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
              imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush,
              new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));

              string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
              filename = "temp" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + extension;
              filename = Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\Ads\" + filename);
              var i2 = new Bitmap(image);
              //  image.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\Ads\" + filename));
              System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\Ads\"));

              i2.Save(filename);                                
         }
    }
}
```

This works fine for all images except `.webp`. When I upload .webp image i get following exception on `Image.FromStream`

> Parameter is not valid

How can i apply watermark on `.webp` image?