# How to add watermark logo while uploading an image in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to add watermark image while uploading image in asp.net mvc.
I am using jquery.uploadfile.min.js multiple file upload for uploading image.
Want to add automatically stored logo image (watermark) to append in my image file that i am going to upload.

IN VIEW:

```
var errorOccured = false;
$(function () {
    var uploadObj = $("#multipleupload").uploadFile({
        url: "./Handler.ashx",
        multiple: true,
        fileName: "myfile",
        maxFileSize: 1024 * 5000,
        allowedTypes: "jpg,jpeg,gif,png",
        autoSubmit: false,
        formData: { "FunctionName": "UploadProductImage", "ProductID": '@clsEncrypt.Encrypt(ViewBag.ProductID.ToString())' }, //"ImgResizeOption": ImgResizeOption
        afterUploadAll: function () {
            if (!errorOccured) {
                window.location.href = 'ProductImage?Product=@(clsEncrypt.Encrypt(ViewBag.ProductID.ToString()))';
            }
        },
        onError: function (files, status, errMsg) {
            alert('file(s) could not be uploaded. Error: ' + errMsg);
            errorOccured = true;
        }
    });

    $("#startUpload").click(function () {
        uploadObj.startUpload();   
    });
});
```

IN HANDLER :

```
    public void UploadProductImage()
    {
        int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(clsEncrypt.Decrypt(HttpContext.Current.Request["ProductID"]));
        string PhysicalFolderPath = "~/Images/Product/";

        for (int j = 0; j < HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count; j++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[j];
            string extention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadFile.FileName);
            UploadPic(uploadFile, j++, PhysicalFolderPath, ProductID);
        }
    }

    protected void UploadPic(HttpPostedFile FUPhoto, int sort, string RemotePath, int ProductID)
    {
        if (FUPhoto.FileName != "")
        {
            string ImgUploadResponse = "";
            string strExt = Path.GetExtension(FUPhoto.FileName).Trim().ToLower();
            string ImageName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() + strExt;
            string OriginalImageFullPath = "~/Images/Product/" + ImageName;
            if (Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Product/")).Equals(false))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Product/"));
            FUPhoto.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(OriginalImageFullPath));

            ProductImageEntity objProdImage = new ProductImageEntity();
            objProdImage.ProductID = ProductID;
            if (ImgUploadResponse != "")
                objProdImage.Image = "";
            else
                objProdImage.Image = ImageName;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objProdImage.Image))
                new ProductImageBLL().InsertUpdateProductImage(objProdImage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870137/automatically-add-watermark-to-an-image

Comment: No problem. I just googled "c# add watermark to image". There are probably many other guides you could follow too, from the search results. Did you do any research of your own?

Comment: I googled it but couldn't found any proper solution, actually i was getting result of adding watermark text while uploading image, But i wanted watermark image to append in my picture. No problem ADyson :) Thanks again ! Have a good day.

Comment: @ADyson using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)) this line giving out of memory exception.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below code for watermark logo to add from code side.

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"))
    using (Image watermarkImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\watermark.png"))
    using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
    {
        int x = (image.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
        int y = (image.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
        watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
        imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width+1, watermarkImage.Height)));
        image.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert_watermark.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome, No prob.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've published a nugget package that do add image water mark with control over opacity and target spot to place the watermark in. Additionally you can add text watermark and do image crop/resize as well.

install via nugget:

`Install-Package LazZiya.ImageResize`

then you can use the code as below:

```
//get image from local path
var img = Image.FromFile("wwwroot\\images\\lum3n-358833-unsplash.jpg");

//scale and crop, 600x250 center focus 
var newImg = ImageResize.ScaleAndCrop(img, 600, 250, TargetSpot.Center);

//watermark image path
var imgWatermark = "wwwroot\\images\\icon.png";

//add image watermark
newImg.ImageWatermark(imgWatermark, 
                TargetSpot.TopRight, //define target spot
                10,                  //margin
                37);                 //opacity (0-100)

//save new image
newImg.SaveAs("wwwroot\\images\\600x250-image-watermark.jpg");

//dispose to free up memory
img.Dispose();
newImg.Dispose();
```

---

### [UPDATE]

The package is updated and some methods has been changed, and better support for more image formats is available (including animated gif).

See [the docs](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.ImageResize/v4.0/index.md) for more details.

see [live demo page](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/ImageResize).

Comment: There are already plenty of imaging libraries available, why create yet another? Also, why use System.Drawing?

Comment: Why another library? same like why another OS? why another car? why another product with similar but competitive features?   `System.Drawing` used to access `Image` class.

Comment: I don't see competitive features compared to other, older, better tested, more feature-rich, more actively maintained image processing libraries. You do know about the trouble with System.Drawing? See for example https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this issue, and I know the rest of the libraries as well. But this doesn't mean that I have to give-up or never do a fresh start. Alternatives will exist all the time.

Comment: btw, I'm using `System.Drawing.Common` the Microsoft-maintained implementation of `System.Drawing` for .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed and tried  your dll. Everything is good but one issue. The watermark text is added vertically to vertical images (images whose height is bigger than width). Better solution is to add watermark in a horizantal line to vertical images as well as horizantal images. Thanks anyway.

--Edit--

I have solved the problem within this code, which checks and changes the orientation of the image in need. (uploadedImage is the image that i read from stream)

```
if (uploadedImage.PropertyIdList.Contains(0x0112))
{
    PropertyItem propOrientation = uploadedImage.GetPropertyItem(0x0112);
    short orientation = BitConverter.ToInt16(propOrientation.Value, 0);
    if (orientation == 6)
    {
        uploadedImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    }
    else if (orientation == 8)
    {
        uploadedImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```