# Writing a watermark over an existing image using C# System.Drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

Basically, I want to add information such as the date and time on a snapshot image of surveillance footage. I don't know to position text in the far top right/left-hand corner. Please any ideas on how I can do this? The programming language that I am using to do this task is C# .Net.

[image: The following image is an example of what I want to achieve.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically add watermark to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870137/automatically-add-watermark-to-an-image)

Comment: Do you want to just have an overlay in the UI or shall it really be part of the image itself?

Comment: @Fildor So I just want to be part of the image itself.