# GDI+ DrawImage notably slower in C++ (Win32) than in C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, gdi+, gdi

I am porting an application from C# (WinForms) to C++ and noticed that drawing an image using GDI+ is much slower in C++, even though it uses the same API.

The image is loaded at application startup into a `System.Drawing.Image` or `Gdiplus::Image`, respectively.

The C# drawing code is (directly in the main form):

```
public Form1()
{
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    this.image = Image.FromFile(...);
}

private readonly Image image;

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.translation.X, this.translation.Y); /* NOTE0 */
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.image.Width, this.image.Height);
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()); // ~3ms
}
```

Regarding `SetStyle`: AFAIK, these flags (1) make `WndProc` ignore `WM_ERASEBKGND`, and (2) allocate a temporary `HDC` and `Graphics` for double buffered drawing.

---

The C++ drawing code is more bloated.
I have browsed the reference source of System.Windows.Forms.Control to see how it handles HDC and how it implements double buffering.

As far as I can tell, my implementation matches that closely (see NOTE1) (note that I implemented it in C++ first and *then* looked at how it's in the .NET source -- I may have overlooked things).
The rest of the program is more or less what you get when you create a fresh Win32 project in VS2019. All error handling omitted for readability.

```
// In wWinMain:
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    gdip_bitmap = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(...);

// In the WndProc callback:
case WM_PAINT:
    // Need this for the back buffer bitmap
    RECT client_rect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &client_rect);
    int client_width = client_rect.right - client_rect.left;
    int client_height = client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top;

    // Double buffering
    HDC hdc0 = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc0);
    HBITMAP back_buffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc0, client_width, client_height); /* NOTE1 */
    HBITMAP dummy_buffer = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc, back_buffer);

    // Create GDI+ stuff on top of HDC
    Gdiplus::Graphics *graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(hdc);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(...);
    graphics->DrawImage(gdip_bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap_width, bitmap_height);
    /* print performance counter diff */ // -> ~27 ms typically

    delete graphics;

    // Double buffering
    BitBlt(hdc0, 0, 0, client_width, client_height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdc, dummy_buffer);
    DeleteObject(back_buffer);
    DeleteDC(hdc); // This is the temporary double buffer HDC

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

`/* NOTE1 */`: In the .NET source code they don't use `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, but `CreateDIBSection` instead.
That improves performance from 27 ms to 21 ms and is very cumbersome (see below).

---

In both cases I am calling `Control.Invalidate` or `InvalidateRect`, respectively, when the mouse moves (`OnMouseMove`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`). The goal is to implement panning with the mouse using `SetTransform` - that's irrelevant for now as long as draw performance is bad.

---

NOTE2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617930/653473

This answer suggests that using `Gdiplus::CachedBitmap` is the trick. However, I can find no evidence in the C# WinForms source code that it makes use of cached bitmaps in any way - the C# code uses `GdipDrawImageRectI` which maps to `GdipDrawImageRectI`, which maps to `Graphics::DrawImage(IN Image* image, IN INT x, IN INT y, IN INT width, IN INT height)`.

---

Regarding `/* NOTE1 */`, here is the replacement for `CreateCompatibleBitmap` (just substitute `CreateVeryCompatibleBitmap`):

```
bool bFillBitmapInfo(HDC hdc, BITMAPINFO *pbmi)
{
    HBITMAP hbm = NULL;
    bool bRet = false;

    // Create a dummy bitmap from which we can query color format info about the device surface.
    hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 1, 1);

    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Call first time to fill in BITMAPINFO header.
    GetDIBits(hdc, hbm, 0, 0, NULL, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    if ( pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount <= 8 ) {
        // UNSUPPORTED
    } else {
        if ( pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS ) {
            // Call a second time to get the color masks.
            // It's a GetDIBits Win32 "feature".
            GetDIBits(hdc, hbm, 0, pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight, NULL, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        }
        bRet = true;
    }

    if (hbm != NULL) {
        DeleteObject(hbm);
        hbm = NULL;
    }
    return bRet;
}

HBITMAP CreateVeryCompatibleBitmap(HDC hdc, int width, int height)
{
    BITMAPINFO *pbmi = (BITMAPINFO *)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 4096); // Because otherwise I would have to figure out the actual size of the color table at the end; whatever...
    bFillBitmapInfo(hdc, pbmi);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    if (pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression == BI_RGB) {
            pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    } else {
        if ( pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount == 16 )
            pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * 2;
        else if ( pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount == 32 )
            pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * 4;
        else
            pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    }
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    void *dummy;
    HBITMAP back_buffer = CreateDIBSection(hdc, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &dummy, NULL, 0);
    LocalFree(pbmi);
    return back_buffer;
}
```

Using a *very* compatible bitmap as the back buffer improves performance from 27 ms to 21 ms.

Regarding `/* NOTE0 */` in the C# code -- the code is *only* fast if the transformation matrix *doesn't* scale. C# performance drops slightly when upscaling (~9ms), and drops significantly (~22ms) when downsampling.

This hints to: `DrawImage` probably *wants* to BitBlt if possible. But it can't in my C++ case because the `Bitmap` format (that was loaded from disk) is different from the back buffer format or something.
If I create a new *more compatible* bitmap (this time no clear difference between `CreateCompatibleBitmap` and `CreateVeryCompatibleBitmap`), and then draw the original bitmap onto that, and then only use the *more compatible* bitmap in the `DrawImage` call, then performance increases to about 4.5 ms. It also has the same performance characteristics when scaling now as the C# code.

```
if (better_bitmap == NULL)
{
    HBITMAP tmp_bitmap = CreateVeryCompatibleBitmap(hdc0, gdip_bitmap->GetWidth(), gdip_bitmap->GetHeight());
    HDC copy_hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc0);
    HGDIOBJ old = SelectObject(copy_hdc, tmp_bitmap);
    Gdiplus::Graphics *copy_graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(copy_hdc);
    copy_graphics->DrawImage(gdip_bitmap, 0, 0, gdip_bitmap->GetWidth(), gdip_bitmap->GetHeight());
    // Now tmp_bitmap contains the image, hopefully in the device's preferred format
    delete copy_graphics;
    SelectObject(copy_hdc, old);
    DeleteDC(copy_hdc);
    better_bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(tmp_bitmap, NULL);
}
```

BUT it's still consistently slower, there must be something missing still. And it raises a new question: Why is this *not* necessary in C# (same image and same machine)? `Image.FromFile` does *not* convert the bitmap format on loading as far as I can tell.

Why is the `DrawImage` call in the C++ code still slower, and what do I need to do to make it as fast as in C#?

Comment: Are you timing the Release build in `c++`?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, C++ times recorded with /O2 in Release.

Comment: Are you timing one single DrawImage call?

Comment: @TaW One `DrawImage` call per measurement, many measurements. Ignore the first few calls. If you're hinting at inaccurate measurements -- no: The variance is tiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up replicating more of the .NET code insanity.

The magic call that makes it go fast is `GdipImageForceValidation` in `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile`. This function is basically not documented at all, and it is not even [officially] callable from C++. It is merely mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-image-flat

`Gdiplus::Image::FromFile` and `GdipLoadImageFromFile` don't actually load the full image into memory. It effectively gets copied from the disk every time it is being drawn. `GdipImageForceValidation` forces the image to be loaded into memory, or so it seems...

My initial idea of copying the image into a more compatible bitmap was on the right track, but the way I did it does not yield the best performance for GDI+ (because I used a GDI bitmap from the original HDC). Loading the image directly into a new GDI+ bitmap, regardless of pixel format, yields the same performance characteristics as seen in the C# implementation:

```
better_bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(gdip_bitmap->GetWidth(), gdip_bitmap->GetHeight(), PixelFormat24bppRGB);
Gdiplus::Graphics *graphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(better_bitmap);
graphics->DrawImage(gdip_bitmap, 0, 0, gdip_bitmap->GetWidth(), gdip_bitmap->GetHeight());
delete graphics;
```

Even better yet, using `PixelFormat32bppPARGB` further improves performance substantially - the premultiplied alpha pays off when the image is repeatedly drawn (regardless of whether the source image has an alpha channel).

It seems calling `GdipImageForceValidation` effectively does something similar internally, although I don't know what it really does. Because Microsoft made it as impossible as they could to call the GDI+ flat API from C++ user code, I just modified `Gdiplus::Image` in my Windows SDK headers to include an appropriate method. Copying the bitmap explicitly to PARGB seems cleaner to me (and yields better performance).

Of course, *after* one finds out which undocumented function to use, google would also give some additional information: https://photosauce.net/blog/post/image-scaling-with-gdi-part-5-push-vs-pull-and-image-validation

GDI+ is not my favorite API.